# How can I automate Google Translate with Autohotkey?

Tags: automation, autohotkey, google-translate

I would like to create an AHK script which..:

1. opens a *new chrome tab*
2. put the *cursor into the search bar*
3. *types* "translate"
4. than press *TAB* (to trigger the quick search(?*) feature
   *(idk the correct name for it  sry)*
5. Press *ENTER*
6. *[than i can just type what I want to translate, so its even faster, than manualy open a new trab, and type*

(If you have other suggestions to solve the problem without AHK, don't hesitate to share. The aim is for the fastest possible translation.)

**SEE THE PIC FOR "flowchart":**

[image: "flowchart"]

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just use a hotkey to navigate to translate and then type your query?

Comment: **IF** the cursor is in that field where I have to type the word, maybe yes!

 Also there is a UX quackery, that I have to "wait" for loading the G translate page for a 0.1 sec...and it feels more fluent, when you type the word, and just wait for the translation, rather than wait for the translation window after type the word...( but it's pure speculation, I Would like to try your version)

Comment: I think you can use the google translate API to get the info directly into a variable, and people have written functions a few times that accomplish this.  On their forums is a working version for Spanish to English, but it doesn't work with East Asian languages for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

I will offer you an alternative solution. The following will open an [InputBox](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/InputBox.htm) and then Chrome with the text you entered and the translation.

```
InputBox, toTranslate
run, chrome.exe https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/"%toTranslate%"
```

Example: Inputting "Buenos días" opens [`https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Buenos días`](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Buenos%20d%C3%ADas)

Comment: WOW! This solution is just OP.
Thank you so much! 
Now I try to use your method to implement into an "add new item to my GTD Inbox" - hotkey. 
[ http://help.nirvanahq.com/category/getting-more-from-nirvana/add-your-items/#create-inbox-items-via-email ]
(basically it's just an email to my custom address)

Answer (score 1):

I'm on a Mac right now, so this is from memory, but the following should trigger translate when you hit F10 in Chrome...

```
#IfWinActive Chrome
F10::
    Send ^T
    Sleep 100
    Send translate
    Sleep 100
    Send {Tab}
    return
#IfWinActive
```

You'll need to hit enter yourself, since it won't know when you're done typing.

If it doesn't work at all, then my `#IfWinActive` line is wrong.

Now, when you hit F10, you might find it stops at some point - maybe it opens a new tab, but never enters translate mode. That probably means it needs a longer Sleep delay (in ms) between those elements. Tweak those 100s as necessary - maybe change them all to 1000 to make sure the code works in principle, then reduce them until you find the right point. They might not even be needed at all, in which case, you could just do it as a one-liner:

```
F10::^Ttranslate{Tab}
; Bonus: translate highlighted word or phrase.
!F10::^C^Ttranslate{Tab}^V{Enter}
```

Bonus bonus: you can create your own search engines by rightclicking on the search bar and clicking "Search engines...", which means you can create two search engines with shortcut names like "translate-spanish" ("https://translate.google.com/#es/en") and "translate-portuguese" ("https://translate.google.com/#pt/en"), and give them separate hotkeys, to be sure you translate the right language without having to mess about clicking languages.

Answer (score 1):

Dewi Morgan's (THYSM bro!) code a bit botched:

```
F10::
 Run Chrome
 Sleep 100
 Send ^T
 Sleep 100
 Send translate.goolge.com
 Sleep 100
 Send {Tab}
 Sleep 100
 Send {Tab}
  Return
```

--> this code works for me.

For some reason there is **TWO** tabs needed. (!!!)

(*OMG "my" first code which is useful somehow in everyday life, not just a data analytic stuff :D:D*)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this ahk scripting code - you can simple type any text and select any text on your system and the computer find automatic out what browser it must use and where it can do the google Translation with query parameters for example translate to us. YOU CAN DO AN TRANSLATION IN ONE BUTTON CLICK (select any text then click F8 key on the keyboard and it is done.)

```
f8:: ; Select any text and then press f8 - you can do in one buttonclick a Google Translation with query parameters [us] 
; + = Shift
; ! = Alt
; ^ = Ctrl
; # = Win (Windows logo key)

GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ; Chrome or Iron
GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class IEFrame            ; Internet Explorer
GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass ; FireFox
GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class ApplicationFrameWindow ; Edge

If WinActive("ahk_group Browser")
{
send ^c 
sleep 150
send ^t ; CTRL+t this will [open a new tab] + goto adress bar - and use CTRL+L for the active tab + goto address bar
sleep 150
texta = https://translate.google.com/#auto/us/
textb = %clipboard% ;selected text
clipboard=%texta%%textb%
sleep 150
send ^v ; paste the selected text
sleep 150
send {enter} 
clipboard=%textb%
} else {
send ^c ;copy the selected text to clipboard memory
sleep 150
texta = https://translate.google.com/#auto/us/
textb = %clipboard% ;selected text

clipboard=%texta%%textb%
run %clipboard%
clipboard=%textb%
}

return
```

Tip: I use it with buttoncommander software (you can test it out the 30 days trial) - With this you can make on your desktop, your own set of favorite toolbar buttons, any button can execute autohotkey command scripts from pictures. You can make for example images with languages Flags. Push it with your mouse or touch device and it is done.  [Click Here](http://www.buttoncommander.com/)